# Graph that depicts time and space on R

Tags: r, graph, graphics

I was trying to think of a good way to depict time and space together for an explanatory graph. My data consists of pedestrian fatality rates in 2019 (the data is per minute) and it is for all the states in the United states.

I was thinking of having a box plot for each state, or possibly having two separate graphs where one is a count plotted on the US Map (below) and the second is a simple line graph plotting national pedestrian fatalities per month.

[image: Data] This data could also be found [here](https://www.nhtsa.gov/content/nhtsa-ftp/280561)

```
#Libraries rm(list=ls()) # this is to clear anything  in memory library(leaflet) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(ggmap) 
library(leaflet.extras) 
library(htmltools) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(maps) 
library(mapproj) 
library(mapdata) 
library(zoo) 
library(tsibble)
#US States  
s<-map_data('state')  ggplot(s,aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=region))+geom_polygon(color='black')+coord_map('polyconic')+guides(fill=F) 
c <- read_csv(file.choose())  view(c)  usa <- c %>% group_by(STATENAME) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% arrange(desc(count))  view(usa)  usa$STATENAME <-tolower(usa$STATENAME)
# view(usa)  
data <- merge(s, usa, by.x='region', by.y='STATENAME')
# view(data)  
ggplot(data, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=count))+ geom_polygon()  ggplot(data, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=count))+ geom_polygon(color='gray')+coord_map('polyconic')+ scale_fill_gradient2(low='white',high='red')+theme_void()+ggtitle('Pedestrian Traffic Fatality in US: 2019')
```

[image: Here is the image it outputted]

Comment: Hi @Moe, it would be helpful if you could add some data and show some of graphs you have already attempted. Graphing is a multidimensional problem as you know and is better shown than described - even if what you show is rough.

Comment: Also, since there are so many different choices it would help to know what kinds of patterns you're looking for.  Are you interested in spatial structure (in which case you might want to plot regions together)? The temporal/seasonal patterns?  Just a few summary statistics for each state?

Answer (score 1):

One option that sounds suitable is the horizon plot: https://rdrr.io/github/hrbrmstr/ggalt/man/geom_horizon.html

E.g.
[image: example_1.png]

If you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you will likely get a better answer.